# Angular 6 and Material design form: element name and icon

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to edit a form in Angular 6 + Material Design. In the above code, I have two problems.

First, if I try to change the default formControlName to test I see the following error. Why? How can I fix it?

Second, I would change the fa-envelope icon and I have searched in the Material Design folder, according to the tutorial I found. But no icon info or link was there; how are icons in material design managed? How can I change it?

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="registrationForm">
    <div class="mt-4">
    <mat-icon matPrefix fontSet="fa" fontIcon="fa-envelope" class="fa-24px text-center mr-3"></mat-icon>
    <mat-form-field class="w-100">
       <input type="email" formControlName="test" matInput placeholder="Deine Name" required="required">
    </mat-form-field>
(...)
```

### Edit

I already have had the instruction

```
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
```

according to the tutorial https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIcon; and now, where I can find the icon name list and in which syntax should I write? For example, I tried "face" both in middle of my icon tag and in the "fontIcon" parameter but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you share your `.ts` code? I guess you have not declared `test` `FormControl` in your `reactive form`

Comment: you have to define formGroup and FormControl in your .ts file

Comment: Thank you very much for the very quick reply, I share now as edit of my question this file.

Comment: First part of the problem solved, thank both! Any suggestion about the icons?

Comment: add code like this `<mat-icon>
          email
        </mat-icon>`

Comment: Thank Abishek, but the question is: in that row, how can I change some parameters to change the icon?I should use this sintax, I suppose. And what is the path of icon set folder when Material Design is installed on Angular? I need to see the icon structure to see the correct name of each icon and choose what is good for me. Ok, may be I will edit my question to make is a little bit more clear. Thank.

Comment: Check my answer edit, that should help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using default material icons

`<mat-icon>envelope</mat-icon>`

2. Using SVG icons

`<mat-icon svgIcon="envelope"></mat-icon>`

3. Using font set (like FontAwesome)

`<mat-icon fontSet="fa" fontIcon="envelope"></mat-icon>`

More here [Icon | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIcon)

## Edit

Icons list available here [Icons - Material Design](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline)

You should really read more about [Material Design](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) and using icons with [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview).

Comment: Ok, but I suppose my default app has already some icons installed but I can't find; when Material Design is installed in Agular, what is the path of the icon set folder? Thank you very much. And I suppose, I should change the value of attributre "fontIcon" with the name of icon, right?